# Multiples sockets TCP listening in the same PORT Python

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, tcp, port

I stablish a TCP connection with a host and my machine is listening in the port X. Can I create new sockets which listen in the same port? I am developing in Python, I think that the language is not a issue, but one friend is developing in C and can do it and I can't. It says me that the port is already in use when I want to do the bind. This is my connection code:

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
list_sock.bind((myIp,myPort))
list_sock.connect((dstAddress,dstPort))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Two sockets cannot listen on the same port, so no.

Comment: I though that, but since my friend can do it...

Comment: Are you sure your friend is not binding sockets to the same port on different interfaces?

Comment: Two answered questions related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212789/multiple-processes-listening-on-the-same-port

Comment: Maybe your friend is using UDP rather than TCP?  It is possible to have multiple sockets receive on the same UDP port (via SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT), but not with TCP.

Comment: you cannot listen on the same port.. but you can accept multiple requests on the same port by spinning out threads to handle each incoming request..