# Running a Python web server twice on the same port on Windows: no "Port already in use" message

Tags: python, windows, networking, windows-7, bottle

I'm on Windows 7. When I start a Bottle web server with:

```
run('0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

And then **once again** run the same Python script, it *doesn't* fail with a  `Port already in use` error (this should be normal behaviour), but instead successfully starts the Python script again!

**Question: How to stop this behaviour, in a simple way?**

This is related to [Multiple processes listening on the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212789/multiple-processes-listening-on-the-same-port), but how can you prevent this in a Python context?

Comment: Check if the port is already opened before opening it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Windows specific behavior that requires the use of the `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` option before binding a network socket.

From the [**Using SO_REUSEADDR and SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE** article in the Windows Socket 2 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinSock/using-so-reuseaddr-and-so-exclusiveaddruse):

> Before the SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE socket option was introduced, there was
>   very little a network application developer could do to prevent a
>   malicious program from binding to the port on which the network
>   application had its own sockets bound. In order to address this
>   security issue, Windows Sockets introduced the SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE
>   socket option, which became available on Windows NT 4.0 with Service
>   Pack 4 (SP4) and later.
>
> ...
>
> The SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE option is set by calling the setsockopt
>   function with the optname parameter set to SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE and the
>   optval parameter set to a boolean value of TRUE before the socket is
>   bound.

---

In order to do this using the Bottle module, you have to create a custom backend facilitating access to the socket before it's bound. This gives an opportunity to set the required socket option as documented.

This is briefly described in the [Bottle Deployment documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html#switching-the-server-backend):

> If there is no adapter for your favorite server or if you need more
>   control over the server setup, you may want to start the server
>   manually.

---

Here's a modified version of the [Bottle Hello World example](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle#example-hello-world-in-a-bottle) that demonstrates this:

```
import socket
from wsgiref.simple_server import WSGIServer
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
  return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

class CustomSocketServer(WSGIServer):
  def server_bind(self):
    # This tests if the socket option exists (i.e. only on Windows), then
    # sets it.
    if hasattr(socket, 'SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE'):
      self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE, 1)

    # Everything below this point is a concatenation of the server_bind
    # implementations pulled from each class in the class hierarchy.
    # wsgiref.WSGIServer -> http.HTTPServer -> socketserver.TCPServer

    elif self.allow_reuse_address:
      self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
    self.server_address = self.socket.getsockname()
    host, port = self.server_address[:2]
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
    self.server_port = port
    self.setup_environ()

print "Serving..."
run(host='localhost', port=8080, server_class=CustomSocketServer)
```

Note that the code copied is required to maintain the expected behavior by the super classes.

All of the super class implementations of `server_bind()` start by calling their parent classes `server_bind()`. This means that calling any of them results in the immediate binding of the socket, removing the opportunity to set the required socket option.

---

I tested this on Windows 10 using Python 2.7.

First instance:

```
PS C:\Users\chuckx\bottle-test> C:\Python27\python.exe test.py
Serving...
```

Second instance:

```
PS C:\Users\chuckx\bottle-test> C:\Python27\python.exe test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 32, in <module>
    server_class=CustomSocketServer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 151, in make_server
    server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 417, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "test.py", line 19, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

Comment: I added an explanation of why the steps taken in the example are necessary.

Comment: Does this not answer your question?

Comment: Cool, just making sure I wasn't missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use @LuisMuñoz's comment: [check if the port is already opened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19196218/1422096) before opening it again:

```
# Bottle web server code here
# ...

import socket
sock = socket.socket()
sock.settimeout(0.2)  # this prevents a 2 second lag when starting the server
if sock.connect_ex(('127.0.0.1', 80)) == 0:
    print "Sorry, port already in use."
    exit()

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```